# Audience response software where data is stored locally

Tags: web-apps, data, secure

Thank you for reading.

I'm looking for an audience polling/response system that can be used during a presentation in front of a live audience, allowing for audience members to vote for various options on their personal mobile devices. However, I am also looking for the ability to store this data locally, without it first being sent to a server. I understand that this may be impossible, especially as the mobile device would have to be connected to the internet and connect to the software provider's server (I'm sorry-- not sure if I'm getting all the terminology correct).

I'm basically looking for someone to either confirm or deny this. I have also looked into self-hosting, but I'm unsure about the details.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you might be able to provide!

Cheers

Comment: I think the only way to get this working is to have a self-hosted solution that you run locally. The users would then access your computer, so to speak. Otherwise you need to trust any web server involved whats done with your data. Alternatively you could look for tools that might have pear 2 pear encryption. Or tools that adhere to stricter privacy regulations like the GDPR and CCP (e.g. PollUnit).